# Semantic ui center aligned button

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I've designed a sign up box for my website using semantic ui. I used semantic ui card for image and it's center aligned. Then I put "Upload a photo" button underneath the image(not fluid because I need the button resize to the width of image when mobile). 
I gave width for button manually and center it. Now it's looking good. The problem is the mobile version. It didn't scale to the image size when mobile because it's fixed width.

[image]
This is my code

```
<button className="fluid ui large red button upload-btn">Upload a Photo</button>

.driver-upload-btn{
  width: 30.4%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Do I need  media query? I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px){

  .driver-upload-btn{
     width: 10.4%; //set width as whatever u want
  }

}

// Media query list

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px){}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px){}
```